# How does the kernel stores the read string input from the user in MIPS?

Tags: kernel, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

The instructions to read and store string input from the keyboard is not clear in MIPS. How is the read string put into the label namespace?

```
.data
    namespace: .space 20
.txt
    li $v0,8
    la $a0,namespace
    li $a1,20
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel can use user-space memory mappings and addresses, and you passed it the address in `$a0`.  You also passed the buffer length in `$a1`, so it knows how many bytes it's allowed to store.

So the kernel gets data from an I/O device and then uses `sw` or `sb` instructions to store it into the buffer you passed.

(Or if you're using MARS / SPIM, `syscall` traps to the interpreter / emulator / simulator code, and isn't running MIPS instructions at all.  Unlike a real MIPS machine running Linux or whatever.)